# Does Android Speech Synthesis do not work for HTC Dream firmware version 1.6 build DRD20?

Tags: android

I have a HTC Dream firmware version 1.6 build DRD20. 
I am unable to install voice data in Menu ==> Settings ==> Speech Synthesis ==> Install voice data. The option just brings me back to previous screen of settings. I also tried installing Speech Synthesis Data Installer and many other applications for text to speech. But none works and give back Sorry! Force close error. Is there any way by which I can install voice data ? Or any way I can use text to speech ?
Can anyone also tell what is latest offical firmware available for this mobile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own old question. Text to speech did not work in any case. But now installed  cynogenmod 6.1 running Froyo made it possible installing voice data .. and now everything .. all apps using TTS feature works !